# Get device location in latitude-longitude in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, location, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a scanner in my application, and as I am scanning any QR code I need to get a current location of device in latitude-longitude. I don't have any idea how to get location so I don't have any piece of code right now. Suggest me some ways to get location on scanning completion of QR code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Geolocator Plugin example:

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync (timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Status: {0}", position.Timestamp);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Latitude: {0}", position.Latitude);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Longitude: {0}", position.Longitude);
```

Ref: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator

Comment: I'm using this method in my OnAppearing method, however the App crashes after GetPositionAsync, do you know what it can be?

Comment: Hi, I am using this plugin in my xamarin android project but  I am getting task cancellation exception. I  have tested in both simulator and real device both getting same result.

Comment: Make sure that `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` are checked in the Android Solution Properties

Comment: Hi @MichaelYuwono , i am trying to get the position of current location on app sleep mode. but i can't get it using this code, var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(); please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

For everyone that is confused about this location stuff I recommend using Xamarin Essentials and not the plug-in mentioned above.

```
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();                                
            if (location != null)
            {
                MyLocation = location;
                if (!ShowUserLocation)
                    ShowUserLocation = true;
            }
```

Comment: But is it crossplatform? I want everything at xamarin forms level, not android or ios.

Comment: yes @MYil its crossplatform
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Xamarin Essentials.
Look this post and check your permissions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android

```
var Latitude;
var Longitude;    
var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);
                    var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

                    if (location != null)
                    {
                        if (location.IsFromMockProvider)
                        {
                            //Put a message if detect a mock location.
                        }else
                        {
                            Latitude=location.Latitude;
                            Longitude=location.Longitude;
                        }
                    }
```