# Storing the city or location where mobile app is used

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to be able to store the city or location where a mobile app am building is been used. This will be tracked when user login to the app. I was reading about Geolocation but not very clear. Is this possible? I am using xamarin forms. Any links will be appreciated.

Comment: Geolocation is using the device's GPS to get the lat/long of the user's position.  Then you would use a reverse geocode service to translate that into an actual address.  XF has a geolocator plugin that will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Do you have an example I can check? do you have any link to any documentation that can be helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get device location in latitude-longitude in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137560/get-device-location-in-latitude-longitude-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Please use CrossGeolocator

```
var position = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync (timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
double lat  = position.Latitude;
double long = position.Longitude;
```

You can follow this github for this purpose:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

---

Also I would suggest you to request for permissions first.